# Different representation of $\sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm learning trigonometry, and I was just looking at the $y = \sin^2(x)$ graph. To me it looks the same as a $y = -\cos(x)$ shifted up. More specifically, it looks like $y = -0.5\cos(2x) + 0.5$ . Are these two functions the same? And this is my first post here so I'm not sure how good of a question this is. Thanks.

Comment: They are the same, that expression is a common identity

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$ thus:

$$
\sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}
$$

Likewise, $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1$ and thus:

$$
\cos^2(x) = \frac{\cos(2x) + 1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would like to underline that relationship $\sin(x)^2 =0.5 -0.5\cos(2x)$ can as well be considered as the **Fourier series development** of $\sin(x)^2$, which - quite an exception - is "exact" with only two terms.

One can in particular recognize that the presence of $\cos(2x)$ means that there is a single harmonic with a frequency doubling (see figure : $y=\sin(x)$ in red, $y=\sin^2(x)$ in blue ; note that, by squaring, simple roots become double roots).

A similar remark can be made for the twin formula $\cos(x)^2 =0.5 +0.5\cos(2x)$.

[image]